# Should re-tagging really be considered as edit?

Tags: discussion, tags, editing

I have seen recently that, When I re-tag a question, It is considered as edit. Then I can even reverse my vote on that question. I have a feeling that, It should not be considered as edit since, The actual meaning of the question is not changed. Also I think, very few of the answerer get information from tag. (I also answered a question, where OP put only a [xubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/xubuntu) tag to inform me, he is using xubuntu. later I have to edit that answer). 
Also, someone might misuse this feature for removing their upvotes.

So, my question is, Why re-tagging should be considered as edit?

My view is: You have given the chance to re-vote the question after edit, because in that way, you can re-judge the question and can give your vote accordingly. As, simply re-tagging doesn't change the meaning of the question, why should you be given the chance to re-merit the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to me that re-tagging may *clarify* the meaning of a question, which could cause someone to change their mind about a vote (either up or down).

- In particular, I've noticed that some questions that are not bug reports but have the [crash](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/crash) tag are downvoted, perhaps because people don't read closely enough to see that the question is actually about how to investigate a crash or report a bug. When that tag is removed and a more specific and appropriate tag is added (like [bug-reporting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/bug-reporting) or [debugging](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/debugging)), those voters might realize that the question doesn't deserve a downvote. They should be able to reverse their vote under these circumstances.
- This also applies to upvotes. A wrongly tagged question might seem good, but turn out to be poorly researched or to lack important information when retagging reveals it's about something else.

Also, a question is sometimes retagged to add information provided in a comment. OP's should usually be editing their questions to provide new information rather than posting comments, but it still does sometimes make sense to change a vote on a question in response to new information provided by the OP in a comment. We can't provide for this in general while still restricting vote reversal, but we can cover some useful cases by allowing vote reversals when the question is retagged.

Comment: Tags make the site work, some people give them too less value :/